# What is the InVmConnectionFactory in the JMS configuration for JBoss?

Tags: jms, jboss7.x

I am new to JBoss and JMS.    What does the `InVmConnectionFactory` mean in the following code block?  My understanding is the JMS queues are created in Java Virtual Memory itself; it doesn't need activeMQ or some other software to create the JMS Queue.

```
 <jms-connection-factories>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
            <connectors>
                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
            </connectors>
            <entries>
                <entry name="ConnectionFactory"/>
            </entries>
        </connection-factory>
    </jms-connection-factories>
```

Answer (score 2):

The InVm connector is used for you inside of the JVM only.  It means that this connection factory is not externally available (if you were to connect to a remote JVM via JNDI, it wouldn't be present).